# "Popover" for user input

Tags: ios

I want to display a small view that does not cover the whole screen with:

- label (some description)
- two text fields (name, mobile number)
- two buttons (Order, cancel)

The view should in a `UIAlertView` sort of way to collect user input. Furthermore, the view has to have a custom layout (colors).

I can't seem to find any built-in ways of doing it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [UIPopOverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)? By subclassing you can customize it any number of ways you want to. While the default is display a UITableView you can change it to whatever you want to display.

If you want this to work on an iPhone you will need to look at a third party API. [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) API is a great choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is just what I need except that it is exclusive to the iPad: "_Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception."_. I am developing for iOS 5. Any other suggestions?